# wysiwyg upload image as background

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files

I learn how to upload images by using IMCE Wysiwyg bridge module.

How about upload images and treat it as background picture?

Comment: you just need to use css to make them background images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the module [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) suit your need. one of the effects that it provide is :

> Watermarking - a much requested addition that enables you to place any
>   image anywhere over a source picture, with alpha transparency